# ViewPager Issue while Scrolling

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

When I am scrolling the viewpager from tab0 to tab1 then tab1 is shown correctly but it hitting the tab2 webservice. similiary when tab2 is shown then it's hitting tab3 webservice.

```
public class OrderDetailsTab extends Fragment {
    View view;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, container, false);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("STATUS"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TRUCKS"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("CHARGES"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("QUOTES"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
        MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter=new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
        myPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        myPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(viewPager.getCurrentItem());

        return view;

    }
    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends DetailPagerAdapter{
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 4;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return StatusTab.init(0);
                case 1:
                    return TruckInfoTab.init(1);
                case 2:
                    return ApprovalTab.init(2);
                case 3:
                    return QuotesFragment.init(3);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

    }

}
```

Abstract Adapter Class:

```
public abstract class DetailPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    // Sparse array to keep track of registered fragments in memory
    private SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

    public DetailPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Register the fragment when the item is instantiated
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    // Unregister when the item is inactive
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    // Returns the fragment for the position (if instantiated)
    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        Log.e("pos---", "" + position);
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by default viewpager will load one extra page to make experience  smooth.

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int);// default is one

Its normal situation and wont affect functionality, as you need to display service data in  corresponding fragment.
Ex : Fragment 01 : display service 01 data and so on .

Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
     * current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
     * limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
     *
     *

This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
     * of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in place
     * on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in perceived smoothness
     * of paging animations and interaction. If you have a small number of pages (3-4)
     * that you can keep active all at once, less time will be spent in layout for
     * newly created view subtrees as the user pages back and forth.

*
     *

You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex layouts.
     * This setting defaults to 1.

Comment: I hade made viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0); but when i come to tab1 it's still hitting the tab2 webservice call. Actually when i am changing the data from the database then tab1 data is not changing , but when i am returning from tab3 then it changing the data

Comment: it is invalid to use 0 in viewPager.setOffscreenPagou eLimit(0);  as i said in my above answer default int value is 1. if you provide 0 , then it will replaced by 1

Comment: try this in your MyDetialpagerAdapter.    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}